# How to change url of Joomla! login module to our custom page?

Tags: php, authentication, joomla

I'd like to change the default value of the login page of Joomla! 3.x to our custom registration page?

Actually, I have two buttons. One to connect, one to register if the user don't have any account on our website. I just want to change the href of the registration button.

I find some answers, but they modify some php file. But what will happen if there is an update of Joomla!?

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my english, i'm french :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you already found what needs to be changed? To make it update safe you'd use overrides:

http://extensions.joomla.org/blog/item/overrides-the-easy-way-to-customise-almost-anything

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides